# What does plus sign does here in string?

Tags: java, string

I would like to know, what is  the difference between two statements, these may be simple

```
      String ss="myname";
      char[] charArray = ss.toCharArray();
      for ( char character : charArray )
         {
            System.out.println( +character );//Statements are here what does plus refers here:

            System.out.println( character ); //Statements are here:

     }
```

I got the output for the code no errors but little doubt on how it works? What happens here?

If you would down vote let me know the reason please.

Comment: The first SOP is printing the ascii value of the character, but not sure how though. Should check the JLS.

Comment: Correct it prints ASCII Thanks for the reply :) @Vikdor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to remember that `char` is still a numeric type.

The `+` here is the unary plus, which does ... nothing. `+x` has the same value as `x`.

**However** `+x` is an `int` while `x` is a `char` in your case. So the effect it has in this case is that `println(int)` is called as opposed to `println(char)` effectively printing the numeric value of your `char` instead of the character represented by it.

The reason why `+x` is an `int` is that the [Unary Operator +](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3) performs a so-called [Unary Numeric Promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1) which "normalizes" numeric values to the types `int`, `long`, `float` and `double` as appropriate.

An easier to understand version of that line would be

```
System.out.println((int) character);
```

It exists *mostly* for the language to be symmetric with regards to the unary minus (`-x`), which returns the negated value of its operand.

See [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) (under "The Unary Operators") for details.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with a fact that ASCII character is using only 7 out of 8 bits so that unary plus clears the MSB "just in case"?

Comment: @VladLazarenko: no, there's nothing of that kind happening here. First of all a `char` is a 16 bit UTF-16 code unit and not a ASCII character and secondly `+` returns the value as is, with no modification at all.

Comment: This kind of high quality answer is what makes StackOverflow such a great resource. Thanks.